# How to trigger same function on different events in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have:

```
<a href={link} on:click={() => func(param)} on:auxclick={() => func(param)}>
   click
</a>
```

Is there any way I can combine `on:click` and `on:auxclick` into `on:click|auxclick`, or something similar to this effect? (Code below gives me a syntax error.)

```
<a href={link} on:click|auxclick={() => func(param)}>
   click
</a>
```

Edit: for clearer description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#use_action) and manually set which events you want listened for:

```js
// multiClicks.js

export const multiClicks = (node, callback) => {
  node.addEventListener('click', callback)
  node.addEventListener('auxclick', callback})

  return {
    destroy() {
      node.removeEventListener('click', callback)
      node.removeEventListener('auxclick', callback})
    } 
  }
}
```

and then use it in your component:

```html
<script>
  import { multiClicks } from './multiClicks.js'
</script>

<a use:multiClicks={() => func(param)}>...</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Nope, this is not possible without creating named function.
And syntax you proposed: `on:click|auxclick={func}` is already reserved by event modifiers feature (you can learn about them from [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-modifiers))

---

In the future you maybe could listen for **all** events - proposal and syntax could be found in [issue on github](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2837)

UPD: Also recommend you to look at @kindoflew answer. You can implement this using custom action.

Answer (score 0):

move your click handler in to a script tag.

```
<script>
function handleClick(event) {
  // do something here
}
</script>

<a href={link} on:click={handleClick} on:auxclick={handleClick}>
   click
</a>
```

Comment: I'm asking if there's any valid syntax that is similar in concept to: `on:click|auxclick={handleClick}`, instead of `on:click` and `on:auxclick` being separated

Comment: A better description probably would have helped then, you can always go back and edit your question. There wont be though as the syntax you want uses an anonymous function which you wont be able to bind to 2 events.